# How to limit FPS for a DirectX application (e.g.: game) if it uses a launcher?

Tags: windows-7, directx, fps

There are many games without an FPS cap. Most of them are free2play. The better PC you have, the more tearing you'll get. (Also, your PC may turn into a heater.)

What I found as a workaround for this problem, is an application called "FPS Limiter". But these free2play games, come with a launcher, which manages the patching process, launching the anti-cheat client, etc.

Is there a way, to force the FPS cap on more files (like I define X.exe (launcher), Y.exe (the game))?
Or a way to debug what does the launcher do, so I can launch it via the command line (AND force the cap?)

(I'm trying to make MicroVolts run like that at the moment, but this question applies to any free2play game out there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was fast, but I found the answer. [DXTORY](http://dxtory.com/top.html) can force a limit. (It's not a free solution, but it works at least.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on **vertical sync (v-sync)** in your graphics card control panel.  This will limit the framerate of any full-screen games to the refresh rate of your monitor, getting rid of the tearing.

Comment: Free 2 play games ignore that setting somehow. I tried to debug the executables and deassembly the launcher, with no success. Back then I checked both nVidia tools and ATI tools.

Comment: Are you sure you set VSync to be *forced* on, or that your drivers aren't overriding it for that particular application?

Comment: Yes, I checked many times. Forced on. No effect.